# Compress python lists that do not fit in memory?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, compression

I have `n` lists of similar sizes, and they are too big to fit in memory simultaneously. My program only needs to access / update one list at a time.

I am thinking of compressing their string representation and store them in a dict. I would simply decompress / compress a list when needed.

Is this a good idea? Are there recommended practices / modules to do that? Better ideas?

Comment: Put them into a file on disk, and stream through them. That is a standard practice for data that is too large to fit in memory.

Comment: You might find this module useful -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylru/1.0.4 as it will manage moving objects between disk and memory.

Comment: For your specific question, yes, you could use cPickle.dumps to get string representations, and if using protocol=-1, you get maximum compression. Whether this is a good idea is another matter. If you said more about what the data was, maybe we could help you more.